# Sort list of files as if they were union mounted - mp3 m3u

Tags: unix, sorting

I'm keeping a collection of music like this:

Music/albums [FLAC]
Music/albums [MP3]

and making m3u playlists like this (run in the Music dir):

```
find "albums [FLAC]" "albums [MP3]" -type f \( -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.flac"  \) -print | sed 's/^\.\///g' | sort  >> "$out_file"
```

but I have multiple situations like this:

```
Music/albums [MP3]/Artist A/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [MP3]/Artist B/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [FLAC]/Artist A/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [FLAC]/Artist B/album title/track.ext
```

All of the albums by a particular artist are not grouped together in the playlist and because of the sorting are at the top or bottom of the list instead.

I experimented with using overlayfs to union mount them - and this works but I am looking for a way of sorting so that the m3u is more like:

```
Music/albums [MP3]/Artist A/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [FLAC]/Artist A/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [MP3]/Artist B/album title/track.ext
Music/albums [FLAC]/Artist B/album title/track.ext
```

I feel like sort should be able to do this or it could be done in Python but would appreciate a nudge in the right direction !

Answer (score 2):

There's `sort` in your pipeline. Tell it what you need:

```
sort -t / -k 3,3 -k 2r,2 -k 4
```

where

- `-t /` specifies delimiter;
- `-k 3,3` tells to sort according to the third field;
- for entries with the same third field, `-k 2r,2` tells to reverse sort according to the second field
- if this is not enough, `-k 4` tells to consider the fourth field and everything that follows.

Note this particular command doesn't sort according to the first field at all. In your example the first field looks fixed: `Music`.

If you don't care if it's MP3 or FLAC, you may want to ignore the second field as well. In such case the sorting should be done according to the third field and everything after. The command for this is much simpler:

```
sort -t / -k 3
```

To learn more see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52762/108618) and `man 1 sort`.